# MongoTemplate findAndModify for document insertion

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Given a document with the below structure:

```json
{
  "_id": "XXXX01",
  "otherAttributes", "....",
  "child": [{
    "_id": "YYYY01",
    "otherAttributes", "....",
    "grandChild": [{
      "_id": "ZZZZ01",
      "otherAttributes", "...."
    }]
  }]
}
```

Using raw mongo dialect, the below are achievable:

**Insert root**

```json
db.collection.findAndModify({
  query: { "_id": "XXXX01" },
  update: {
    "_id": "XXXX01",
    "otherAttributes", "....",
    "child": [{
      "_id": "YYYY01",
      "otherAttributes", "....",
      "grandChild": [{
        "_id": "ZZZZ01",
        "otherAttributes", "...."
      }]
    }]
  },
  upsert: true
})
```

But a similar findAndReplace with mongoTemplate eg.

```java
var document = new Document();
mongoTemplate.getConverter().write(javaObjectRepresentingTheDocument, document);
update = Update.fromDocument(document) // Primary because I dont want to set each field individually
query.addCriteria(
  Criteria.where("id").is("XXXX01")
);
mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update,
  FindAndModifyOptions.options().upsert(true).returnNew(true),
  javaObjectRepresentingTheDocument.getClass(),
  collection
)
```

results in the below error:

```bash
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name _id
  at org.bson.AbstractBsonWriter.writeName(AbstractBsonWriter.java:534) ~[bson-4.4.3.jar:na]
  ...
```

The reason I would want to use `findAndReplace` over `upsert` is:

1. I need the current object
2. Generalize code ie. the same method(`findAndReplace`) is useful for both insertion and updation at all levels viz. the root document, a nested document eg. `child`, a deeply nested document eg. `grandChild`

I have been successful is getting the same work for `child` and `grandChild` nested documents by using

```java
update.addToSet("$[parentSelector]", javaObjectRepresentingTheNestedDocument)
.filterArray(Criteria.where("parentSelector._id").is(<parentSelectorValue>))
```

but not being able to the get the same working for the root document. Can someone provide some guidance?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I am having the same problem.

Best as I can tell, when using findAndModify, internally it's using UpdateFieldNameValidator which requires all fields to start with '$' though I am not sure what it will do when it inserts a document as the default Mongo document id key is '_id' and in my case I am specifying the id value rather than letting mongo assign it.

Seems crazy that the same document that works fine on an .upsert() call gets rejected with BSON error when switching to .findAndModify() with upsert=true. This feels like a gigantic bug to me.